Change of variable in PDE
I have the following PDE (Convection-Diffusion):
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial t} + v\frac{\partial P}{\partial x} = D\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial x^2}$$
And I want to reach the general Diffusion equation:
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial t} = D\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial u^2}$$
I know this can be achieved by performing a change of variable $u= x - vt$, but when I do that, using the chain rule I get: $\frac{\partial P}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial P}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial P}{\partial u}$.
When I substitute that back into the convection-diffusion equation I have: $$\frac{\partial P}{\partial t} + v\frac{\partial P}{\partial u} = D\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial u^2}$$
I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Also it may be important to note that $v^2 = 1-2D$

You are not applying the chain rule correctly to a multi-variable function.

@Vasili How come? Shouldn't it simply be what I did?

You also need to define $\tau=t$. Then $$\partial_tP=\partial_uP\partial_tu+\partial_{\tau}P\partial_t\tau=-v\partial_uP+\partial_{\tau}P.$$

You apply change of variables $x=u+vw, t=w$. The chain rule will apply like so:
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial P}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial P}{\partial w}\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}=P_u$$
and (here lies your problem as $u=x-vt$)
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial P}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial P}{\partial w}\frac{\partial w}{\partial t}=-vP_u+P_w.$$
